# How can I send information from an embeded iframe to my website( where that iframe is embeded on)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, storage, embed

I'm coding a site where I wan't to embed an iframe, the iframe is coded on a different domain/ origin and I wan't to send an string to my website (javascript of the site) everytime I click a button, I can't use sessionstorage or localstorrage because the iframe is not on the same origin as the site!

**update**

I've tried using postmessage, this method is new for me, I've been able to receive messages that I send from the console but I can't send messages from my iframe for some reason, It doesn't work this is the code for the button that needs to send the message `<img id="play"src="https://image source" alt="play" onclick="window.postMessage('{{YTID}}', '*');" height="100" width="100">`  
the button shows up but it won't send.

I think it has something to do with the `window` but I don't know what the right DOM for the receiving window would need to be.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: wow thank you, I've implemented this in my site , but for some reason, it won't send, I can read messages I send from the console and use them but it won't send from the iframe , I'm using   `onclick="window.postMessage(ID, '*');"  ` with ID being the variable I wan't to send.

Comment: Update (edit) your question providing your current (and relevant) code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the post message method [more about that here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

on the sending end I've used `window.parent.postMessage('Message', '*');` the window.parent specefies to send the message to the parent of the iframe which is my website, on the receiving end (on my site) I've used  `window.addEventListener("message", function(message){ more code });`

this does it for me, thank you